# Regex for number of digits 0 and at least one digit 1

Tags: regex, group

I have a block of text in which I try to find lines that contain any (*) number of digits 0 and at least one (+) digit 1. Explaination:

```
 1234   xxx  00000000000111000000  00000010000100000000  Some text <-- matches
 2345   yyy  00000000000000000000  00000000000000000000  Some text <-- does not match
 2345   yyy  00000001000000000000  00000000000000000000  Some text <-- matches
 3456   zzz  11111111111111111111  11111111111111111111  Some text <-- matches
```

How to accomplish this? Thanks!

Tried with negative lookahead but failed:

`\s+\d+ +[a-zA-Z]+ +(?![0]{20}) +(?![0]{20}) +([0-9a-zA-Z ]+)`

Comment: How about this: ```^.*[0]*.*[1]+.*$```

Answer (score 1):

You are not matching any digits 0 or 1 after the assertions.

If both columns with the digits 0 or 1 can not be only zeroes, you can use both columns in the assertion:

`+\d+ +[a-zA-Z]+ +(?!0{20} +0{20}\b)[01]{20} +[01]{20} +([0-9a-zA-Z ]+)`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/J91LGE/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my shorter version of the regex. But it only test line by line. So you will have to iterate through each line in your file like the code below:

```
import re

text = '''1234   xxx  00000000000111000000  00000010000100000000  Some text
2345   yyy  00000000000000000000  00000000000000000000  Some text
2345   yyy  00000001000000000000  00000000000000000000  Some text
3456   zzz  11111111111111111111  11111111111111111111  Some text'''

regex = r'^\d+\s+\w+\s+0*1+0*\s+\d+\s+\w+'

matches = re.findall(regex, text, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

For explanation and details, please check [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wv5Zu1/1) demo

Comment: You hardcoded the order. I mean this does not work for such case when it starts from '1':
2345   yyy  10000001000000000000  00000000000000000000  Some text